# Error: No matching constructor for initialization of 'Matrix_ref<...>'

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++, so please be patient with me.

This is my matrix class

```
template<class T = double> class Matrix {

    using sequence_type = std::vector<T>;

public:

    ... some methods and constructors

    Matrix_ref<T> col(Index i_) { if (i_ < 0 || i_ > r) _error("out_of_bound"); return Matrix_ref<T>(elems.data(), Matrix_slice(i_, r, c), r); }
    Matrix_ref<T> row(Index i_) { if (i_ < 0 || i_ > c) _error("out_of_bound"); return Matrix_ref<T>(elems.data(), Matrix_slice(i_ * c, c, 1), c); }

    const Matrix_ref<T> col(Index i_) const { if (i_ < 0 || i_ > r) _error("out_of_bound"); return Matrix_ref<T>(elems.data(), Matrix_slice(i_, r, c), r); }
    const Matrix_ref<T> row(Index i_) const { if (i_ < 0 || i_ > c) _error("out_of_bound"); return Matrix_ref<T>(elems.data(), Matrix_slice(i_ * c, c, 1), c); }

    Matrix_ref<T> operator[](Index r_) { return row(r_); }


private:
    sequence_type elems;
    Index r;
    Index c;

    ...other methods

};
```

This is a struct that return correct index of an element in a row (practically it calculate the "stride")

```
struct Matrix_slice {

    Matrix_slice(Index first_, Index size_, Index stride_) : first(first_), size(size_), stride(stride_) {}

    const Index first;
    const Index size;
    const Index stride;

    Index operator()(Index i) { return first + stride * i; }
    const Index operator()(Index i) const { return first + stride * i; }
};
```

And this is a "reference" to the matrix. If I use the [] operator with the matrix, I get a matrix_ref.

```
template<class T = double> class Matrix_ref {

public:
    Matrix_ref(T* elems_, Matrix_slice slice_, Index ref_size_) : elems(elems_), slice(slice_), ref_size(ref_size_) {}

    T& at(Index i) { if (i < 0 || i >= ref_size) _error("out_of_bound"); return elems[slice(i)]; }
    const T& at(Index i) const { if (i < 0 || i >= ref_size) _error("out_of_bound"); return elems[slice(i)]; }

    T& operator[](Index i) { return elems[slice(i)]; }
    const T operator[](Index i) const { return elems[slice(i)]; }

    constexpr Index size() const { return ref_size; }

private:
    T* elems;
    const Matrix_slice slice;
    const Index ref_size;

};
```

This is the definition of operator*:

```
template<class T> Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T>& a, const Matrix<T>& b) {
    if (a.cols() != b.rows()) _error("Matrix size mismatch");
    Matrix<T> res(a.rows(), b.cols());
    for (Index i = 0; i < res.rows(); ++i)
        for (Index j = 0; j < res.cols(); ++j)
            res.at(i, j) = a.row(i) * b.col(j);
    return res;
}
```

The problem is here -> operator*(const Matrix& a, const Matrix& b)
If I declare this operator with const Matrix& a and const...b, it doesn't works, but if I declare without const keyword, It works. But I think it's better to use const. How can I fix it? I think the problem is the fact that Matrix_ref has not T* elems declared as const. If I declare it as const, it works, but I can't modify a Matrix. I got the error at the return of the row/col method in Matrix class caused by this line "res.at(i, j) = a.row(i) * b.col(j);" in overload operator* function.

Complete code: https://github.com/H0lm3s/Matrix/tree/master

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: oh yes, sorry I get this error <No matching constructor for initialization of 'Matrix_ref<int>'> at the return of the const row/col method in Matrix class.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as well as putting the exact error you get into the question itself.

Comment: @AndyG hum, I don't know how to recreate a similar example but I can give you all the code so that you can compile and see the error. (I edited the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said the issue is with *constness*.

```
const Matrix_ref<T> col(Index i_) const 
{ 
        if (i_ < 0 || i_ > r) _error("out_of_bound"); 
        return Matrix_ref<T>(elems.data(), Matrix_slice(i_, r, c), r);  // <-- 
}
```

when you call `elems.data()` from *const* method `vector<T>::data()` returns `const T*`,
compiler complains because `const T*` cannot be assigned to `T*` - a risk 
of modifying data. However you know that `row` and `col` methods return
*const* object of your proxy class  `const Matrix_ref<T>` so you can use 
`const_cast` to remove constness from `elemes.data()`, an instance of proxy class will keep pointer to `T`, and because returned object is qualified as `const` only *const* methods can be invoked on this object, this prevents from modifying data in `Matrix` when you are using proxy class.
The use of `const_cast` is safe in this case, so you can change `row` and `col` member functions as follows:

```
const Matrix_ref<T> col(Index i_) const { 
    if (i_ < 0 || i_ > r) _error("out_of_bound"); 
    return Matrix_ref<T>( const_cast<T*>(elems.data()) , Matrix_slice(i_, r, c), r); 
}                      // ^^^
```